# What is the most popular framework for GUI app designing? (JAVA/ C#/ C++)

Tags: gui, .net, framework, qt

I don't care about the application type. Right now I need to just learn one with highest demand of software companies when all different fields are considered together.

Comment: Also, "`mostly used one with highest demand`" could have two different answers.

Comment: I clearly said my requirement. I don't have specifics since I am not targeting any software application right now.All google results I find are targeting specific cases and diffrent type of applications. As a student I just need a general picture to know what is the best to learn right now as my first entry to this area. There I am trying to find the mostly demanded framework by most of the companies. Can you help?

Comment: Forget about "most popular/in demand". I'm trying to find the framework which has the biggest market share (ie: mostly used in the industry regardless of specific fields). My question is that simple.

Comment: If I just search it,all I get are related to specific applications or languages. I don't need any specifics. I'm searching for the mostly used one in the industry when all the fields are considered together.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Stack Overflow's 2019 [developer survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#technology) (probably the most trusted source in programming) the top programming languages are:

1. JavaScript

   - [React](https://reactjs.org/)
   - [Angular](https://angular.io/)
   - [Vue](https://vuejs.org/)
2. Python (used more in data science & back-end coding)
3. Java (used more in back-end coding)
4. C#

   - [ASP.NET Razor Pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)
   - [ASP.NET MVC](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/mvc)
   - [Blazor](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-apps/blazor)

Comment: looks like COBOL is missing ...