# Which GUI framework is mostly used in the software industry for developing standalone desktop apps?

Tags: open-source, software-development, gui, framework, user-interface

As a student I am looking for the mostly used GUI framework in the industry for standalone desktop apps when all the frameworks in all the languages are considered together. Basically I want to know the one with the highest market share.

My requirement is just to start learning it and I don't want to target specific application types.

Comment: "`Basically I want to know the one with the highest market share. `" - then Google is your friend.  Please read [ask] and understand why this question is off-topic and will be closed unless you reword it.

Comment: A [similar question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/72217/what-is-the-most-popular-framework-for-gui-app-designing-java-c-c) which also ought to be closed unless brought up to scratch.

Answer (score 1):

What platform are you interested in? For cross-platform apps the industry seems to be moving toward Electron apps like Slack or Visual Studio Code is built in - it's a framework for embedding Chromium into a desktop app.

For Windows only, there is Windows Forms or Windows Presentation Foundation.

On Linux, Gtk is popular.

In Python, TkInter is included with the language.

Comment: For cross platform, I would add that there is also [Qt](https://www.qt.io/), which is widely used in industry.